# difficulties in wordladder programe

Tags: python, stack, queue

I'm struggling to complete my wordladder programme. Need some guidance.

The following is my source code thus far :
    newQueue = MyQueue()
    newStack = MyStack()

```
#finding words with one letter difference
newStack.push(firstWord)
while True:
    for words in dictionary:
        diffcounter =0;
        if (len(firstWord) == len(words)):
            for i in range(0, len(firstWord)):
                if (firstWord[i] != words[i]):
                    if (diffcounter > 1):
                        break
                    else:
                        diffcounter = diffcounter + 1

            if (diffcounter == 1):
                newStack.push(words)
                newQueue.enqueue(newStack)



#compare with lastWord 
    deStack = newQueue.dequeue()
    print deStack.toString()
    if (deStack.peek() != lastWord):

        #problem
        firstWord = deStack.peek()
    else:
       break
```

So basically, it will go into a infinite loop and once the lastWord is reach, it will break. But now I'm encountering issues with the checking with lastWord. **So far i'm able to extract words with one letter difference but cant loop the function to keep looping until the lastWord is reach.**

Comment: Can you give a description of what the code is supposed to do and what it does instead?

Comment: sample output would be : devil devel level lever leger luger auger anger angel